How to fix: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available
I have installed python3.11 on my new devbox, with system debian 9. Everything goes well, but when I using pip to install requirements, error occurs. The details are as follows.
➜  pip3 install virtualenv
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenv/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/virtualenv/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/virtualenv/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenv
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

I think the key error message is: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available, and
Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")
I have made many efforts:

reinstall python with openssl according to Question: 57586800
install other requirements according to Question: 45954528
set trusted host, like:
pip config set global.trusted-host \
    "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org" \
    --trusted-host=pypi.python.org \
    --trusted-host=pypi.org \
    --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org




Methods above don't work for me. So I wonder what goes wrong?
More details:

Before I compile python, I have run:

sudo apt install libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev libtk8.6 libgdm-dev libdb4o-cil-dev libpcap-dev to install ssl requirements (maybe?)
and then, I run the follow commands to install openssl.

cd /usr/src 
curl openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2o.tar.gz | tar xz 
cd openssl-1.0.2o 
./config shared --prefix=/usr/local/ 
sudo make 
sudo make install


I found the default python2.7 runs well, but python3 doesn't
➜  ~ python3 -V
Python 3.11.3
➜  ~ python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION_INFO)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 100, in <module>
    import _ssl  # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
➜  ~ python -V
Python 2.7.13
➜  ~ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION_INFO)"
(1, 1, 0, 12, 15)


The openssl version that python3.10+ needs should be greater than 1.1.1(Note PEP-644 which requires OpenSSL >= 1.1. 1 is released in Python 3.10
)?  But the openssl in my Debian9 is 1.0.2o.
➜  which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl
➜  openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018

I have upgraded openssl to 3.0 and rebuild python3.10, also doesn't work.
Using pyenv to install python also doesn't. Error, '_ssl' requirement is not satisfied, occurs.

=========================================
Finally, I reinstall the system from debian9 to debian10. The default openssl version is OpenSSL 1.1.1n. All errors disappear.
The problem is fixed.

Did you compiled Python? I mean, not installed a precompiled using apt/dpkg? For compilation 1st you need to install other requirements especially libssl-dev, then recompile Python. (In your questions things go the other way around so I want to make sure.)

Yes. I installed python using source code. Before executed make command,  I had installed requirements, using command sudo apt install libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev libtk8.6 libgdm-dev libdb4o-cil-dev libpcap-dev.  @phd

Then we need more details. When you were compiling Python was module _ssl compiled? Can you [edit] and copy/paste relevant part of compilation process? Can you do python -c "import _ssl; print(_ssl)" with freshly compiled python? python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION_INFO)" ?

Module _ssl was not compiled. Perhaps libssl-dev is not enough or OpenSSL is of a wrong version. To understand the problem please [edit] and copy/paste relevant part of compilation process…

BTW, to install/upgrade different Python versions you can use conda, pyenv or asdf.
